# Break at local label using GDB for NASM assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb, nasm

I want to break at a local label in NASM assembly code using GDB.

Issuing the following command yields the output:

```
   (gdb) break *start.label1 + 217
    Attempt to extract a component of a value that is not a structure.
```

Here my code goes something like this:

```
global _start
_start:
...
.label1:
...
```

How can I break at local `.label1`?

Comment: To break at a label, you shouldn't dereference it `b start.label1`, just like `b main`.  Maybe `b (start.label1 + 217)` would work.  With a dereference, you might need `b *(start.label1 + 217)`.  But IDK if gdb supports `.` inside symbol names, which `nm` says is the actual symbol name.  You might have to `b *0x...` and copy/paste the address.  Sorry don't have time to write an answer.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions :)

Comment: Put the label with the period inside of single quotes in the expression. Something like `b *'start.label1' + 217`

Comment: GNU GAS ELF version of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55226798/how-to-make-local-labels-in-gnu-gas-elf-output-that-gdb-can-break-on-but-not-cou

Answer (score -1):

Disassemble the function where your local label is called, select the address and add a break as you normally would with the address, not the label name. You can also disassemble by the address for local labels.